# How to get laminate stiffness matrices (ABD) in APDL ANSYS?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, finite-element-method, ansys

I am trying to perform structural analysis of composite pressure vessel in APDL/ANSYS. I have completed the solution and now I want to extract ABD matrix.Do anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

For standard layered-shell sections, you can obtain submatrices [ A ], [ B ], [ D ], and [ E ] via the SLIST command's FULL option or via the *GET command (Entity = SHEL).